# 1D array into a 2D string array with C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to create an array with count 16 (array[16]) into a 2D array (array[4][4]).

At first I have an array of 50 strings:

```
    string housewives[50] = {"Vicki", "Tamra", "Shannon", "Kelly", "Peggy", "Heather", "Meghan", "Ramona", "Luann", "Bethenny", "Sonja", "Carole", "Dorinda", "Tinsley", "Alex", "Jill", "Kelly", "Aviva", "Heather", "Jules", "Nene", "Sheree", "Kandi", "Cynthia", "Kenya", "Porsha", "Kim", "DeShawn", "Lisa", "Phaedra", "Claudia", "Teresa", "Melissa", "Dolores", "Margaret", "Danielle", "Jacqueline", "Caroline", "Jacqueline", "Dina", "Siggy", "Kyle", "Erika", "Dorit", "Teddi", "Camille", "Taylor", "Adrienne", "Brandi", "Yolanda"};
```

I then strip it to the first 8:

```
    void stripArray(string array[8], size_t end) {
        for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
            cout << array[i] << endl;
        }
        // this prints out "Ramona Yolanda Cynthia Nene Claudia Kandi Teddi Alex"
        setAnswerArray(array);
};
```

Now I need to double this array so that there are two repeating words:

```
    void setAnswerArray(string array[8]) {
        string *result = new string[8 + 8];
        copy(array, array + 8, result);
        copy(array, array + 8, result + 8);
        for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
            cout <<result[i] << ' ';
        }
        //Now this prints out "Ramona Yolanda Cynthia Nene Claudia Kandi Teddi Alex Ramona Yolanda Cynthia Nene Claudia Kandi Teddi Alex"
};
```

How do I then convert the above array to into a 4x4 2D array?

I know I need to use a for loop and here is what I tried so far:

```
    string matrix[4][4];
    matricize(result, matrix, 4);

 void matricize(string list[16], string matrix[4][4], int rows)
{
    //INPUT THE VALUES OF ONE-DIMENSION ARRAY INTO THE TWO-DIMENSION ARRAY
    int listSize=0;

    for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < rows; counter1++)
    {
        for (int count=0;count < 4; count++)
        {
            matrix[counter1][count] = list[listSize];
            listSize++;
        }
    }
    int width = 4, height = 4;
    for (width=0;width<4;width++)
    {
        for (height=0;height<4;height++)
        {cout<<list[width][height]<<" ";}
        cout<<endl;
    }
};
```

But this prints out:

```
R a m o 
Y o l a 
C y n t 
N e n e
```

Any help is appreciated. I just started learning C++ the past couple months so I'm sure I missed something with the array formations. The problem is from my programming class in case you're wondering why I started with a larger array. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `cout<<list[width][height]`? Did you mean to output `matrix`'s values instead of `list`'s?

Comment: @frslm Yes I did. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are printing the wrong array:

```
cout<<list[width][height]
```

should be

```
cout<<matrix[width][height]
```

The string class has an `operator[]` itself and that is why you don't get a compiler error but just the character at the specified index.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code

```
string matrix[4][4];
```

It means you try to declare an array of string with length 4 string and each string is 4 char length, and it is why you get this result.

```
R a m o  
Y o l a  
C y n t  
N e n e
```

You can copy an array using

```
std::copy();
```

or you can use vector instead.